# Find suggestions based on interests using Laravel and Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, recommendation-engine

I'm building a small site where users can receive movie recommendations based on their preferences for some attributes, such as genre, year or running time. My database looks like the following (the arrows signifies many-to-many relationships):

[image]

Assuming I have a model for each entity in the picture, how do I find which movies I should recommend to a user?

Comment: Generating meaningful and good recommendations is a difficult task. You are basically asking us to do all the work for you. How about you try it yourself and post a question if you come across a problem.

Comment: Not really, I'm asking a purely technical API question. I don't expect you to start throwing recommendation algorithms at me.

Comment: Okay. So you just want all movies that match the genre or year or runtime which the user has a relation to?

Comment: Almost :) I want the movies where each attribute (genre, year, runtime) for a movie has at least one relation to a user. It's a poor example with year (because there would obviously only be one year for a movie), but fx. for a movie with both the 'action' and 'thriller' genre, then the user would have to like at least action or thrillers, or both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for can be accomplished by using `whereHas`:

```
Movies::whereHas('genres.users', function($q) use ($userId){
   $q->where('users.id', $userId);
})->whereHas('years.users', function($q) use ($userId){
   $q->where('users.id', $userId);
})->whereHas('runtimes.users', function($q) use ($userId){
   $q->where('users.id', $userId);
})->get();
```

This basically filters movies by the nested relationship `users` (over the three other relations)